# Dependency injection in Django

Tags: django, factory

I have a factory-object which I'd like to make available to certain views in Django. The factory does not change the any state, it only creates instances. Instead of instantiating the factory in each view I'd like to create one instance and register it on server-startup.

Is this possible in Django and if so how? Otherwise what is the Pythonic/Djangonic way to do it?

Comment: What does the factory do? Regular "Java-like" OO might not be Pythonic at all.. What do you want to acomplish?

Comment: Do you want to generate and store one object across the life of the _server_ or the _request_?

Comment: I want to keep it across the life-time of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to put the code in one of the files imported by Django on startup, such as:

- `settings.py`
- `myapp/__init__.py` where `myapp` is an app in `INSTALLED_APPS` setting var
- `myapp/models.py` where `myapp` is an app in `INSTALLED_APPS` setting var

Your code doesn't have to go in the actual file above, you could put it in a separate file as long as you import *that* from one of the files above.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, Anentropic